# Can I curl a full node on initial sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, geth-debugging

I spun up a few node ~30 minutes ago and I'm not able to make a curl request, not sure if this is normal behaviour during initial sync or if something is somehow misconfigured.

Request:

`curl -X POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:8545`

Response:

`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: is it parity or is it go-ethereum? looks like firewall issues

Comment: post the command you have entered in the shell to run your node

Comment: you can curl a node, and it would respond immediately , 1 second after startup. sync doesn't matter

Comment: Looks like it's definitely firewall/docker networking then. Started geth with `geth --syncmode full --rpc --rpcapi eth net web3 debug txpool --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain *`

Comment: why don't you put `--rpcaddr` with fixed IP instead of 0.0.0.0 and try again